# Unable to hide the div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am able to find the div name using the below code:

```
var id = $("textbox").closest("div").attr("id");
```

How can I hide the div based on above fetched id. I have tried with following code:

```
$(id).hide();
```

It doesn't seems to work

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using the id and don't directly hide the div? `$('textbox').closest('div').hide();`

Comment: what is textbox? if its id, you should use #textbox instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are getting the correct id.

Then use `$('#'+id).hide();`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the #

```
$('#'+id).whatever()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the ID in the first place, just use the jQuery object you already got:

```
$("textbox").closest("div").hide();
```

If you want the ID for later use then store the object locally:

```
var oClosest = $("textbox").closest("div");
oClosest.hide();
var id = oClosest.attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you actually do

```
var myDiv = $("textarea").closest("div");
```

and then just do

```
myDiv.hide();
```